# can "libexcel-writer-xlsx-perl" be added to precise and later?

Tags: 12.04, repository, perl

I am interested in using the Perl module **Excel::Writer::XLSX** on Precise.  I can install it using CPAN, but due to complications at my office, it'd be easier to just be able to do `apt-get install` from the official Ubuntu repositories.

What are the chances of having the Perl module **Excel::Writer::XLSX** (libexcel-writer-xlsx-perl) added to Precise or later?

Answer (score 0):

These two links help? They are links to Excel-Writer-XLSX and the perl module:

http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/

http://jmcnamara.github.io/excel-writer-xlsx/

There is a post on this question [here](http://www.webrichsoftware.com/?p=344): Also a caveat against someone installing through a PPA (command line)due to not having all the files compatible together, I think. Honestly hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Excel::Writer::XLSX** is available as a debian package since Quantal:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libexcel-writer-xlsx-perl

Note, John McNamara also started to port the same module to python and a packaged version is available for Trusty:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xlsxwriter

Answer (score -1):

It's simple under Ubuntu 14.04. Simply do:

```
sudo apt-get install libexcel-writer-xlsx-perl
```